# How to implement Squeeze Box sample code in JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I desire to display a popup. When that popup appears, it has to blur and invalidate the background. The popup contains my content, and it is closed when the user clicks the close button. I choose, squeezbox. but I don't know how to implement it. Please help me with running sample code of squeezebox. I already implemented one set of code, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a modal? Something like [Bootstrap's Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)?

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is an open-source framework, just download it and follow the documentation.

Comment: no iam unable to get and implement the solution. please help me if u dont mind